# How to pipe my function output? TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I am trying to pipe my function output(fileters files by .js) to lang directory

```
const dir = './lang';
let logStream = fs.createWriteStream(dir, {flags: 'a'});
if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
}

function searchFolder(spath,filter){
    const files=fs.readdirSync(spath);
    const nm = 'folder';

    for(let i=0; i<files.length; i++){
        let filename=path.join(spath,files[i]);
        let stat = fs.lstatSync(filename);
        if (stat.isDirectory() && filename.startsWith(nm)){
            return searchFolder(filename,filter);
        }
        else if (filename.indexOf(filter)>=0) {
            console.log('found: ',filename);
        };
    };
}

let output = searchFolder('.','*.js')
console.log(output)
output.pipe(logStream);
```

Got this error

```
output.pipe(logStream);
       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
```

How to fix this?

Comment: `searchFolder` returns void, instead of a stream; do you want to return `fs.createWriteStream(filename)` from that function instead?

Comment: @Federkun Yes,exactly.

Comment: @Federkun How to refactor my code?